# Swift Value of type 'SKNode' has no member 'particleBirthRate'

Tags: swift

I have a scene where meteors (SKSpriteNodes) fall with trails (SKEmitterNodes). Each of these meteors has a unique name that matches the name of its trail.

You can shoot these meteors down, and they are removed upon contact with the bullet. To remove the meteor's accompanying trail, I loop through all existing nodes and delete the one with the same name as the meteor.

This sudden 'disappearance' of the trail looks unnatural, as I want particles that have already been emitted to finish their cycle. Therefore, I wrote the following:

```
for child in children {
        if child.name == meteorite.name {
            child.particleBirthRate = 0 //Stops new particles from being created
            delay(2) {
                child.removeFromParent()
            }
        }
    }
```

XCode's compiler returns:

> Value of type 'SKNode' has no member 'particleBirthRate'

I'm not sure how to work around this, as I know that the node with the same name has to be an SKEmitterNode, but, obviously, the compiler cannot know that, and therefore it returns the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a conditional binding. Something like this:

```
for child in children where child.name == meteorite.name {
    if let emitter = child as? SKEmitterNode {
        emitter.particleBirthRate = 0 //Stops new particles from being created
        delay(2) {
            emitter.removeFromParent()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is a `for` loop with a `case` pattern:

```
for case let emitter as SKEmitterNode in children {
    if emitter.name == meteorite.name {
        emitter.name.particleBirthRate = 0 
        // ...
    }
}
```

The loop body is only executed for nodes of type `SKEmitterNode`.

This can be combined with the `where` constraint:

```
for case let emitter as SKEmitterNode in children where emitter.name == meteorite.name {
    emitter.name.particleBirthRate = 0 
    // ...
}
```